# How to implement this fuzzy search sql query in Opaleye?

Tags: haskell, opaleye

I have an sql query that I am attempting to convert to Opaleye.

I'll simplify my code to focus on the point of my question, namely **how to fuzzy search with Opaleye**.

The Haskell (with some existing Opaleye structures) is

```
namesTable :: O.Table NamesColumnWrite NamesColumnRead
namesTable = O.Table "names" (pNames Names { id = O.optional "id"
                                            , licenseNumber = O.required "license_number"
                                            , fullName = O.required "full_name"
                                            })

import qualified Database.PostgreSQL.Simple as PGS

data Names' id' licenseNumber' fullName' =
    Names
        { id           :: id'
        , licenseNumber     :: licenseNumber'
        , fullName          :: fullName'
        } deriving (Show, Eq)

namesQuery :: Query NamesColumnRead
namesQuery = queryTable NamesTable

type NamesRead = Names' Int String String
type NamesWrite = Names' (Maybe Int) String String
type NamesColumnWrite = Names' (Maybe (O.Column O.PGInt4)) (O.Column O.PGText) (O.Column O.PGText)
type NamesColumnRead = Names' (O.Column O.PGInt4) (O.Column O.PGText) (O.Column O.PGText)

getNamesByFuzzyLicenseNumber :: PGS.Connection -> String -> IO [NamesRead]
getNamesByFuzzyLicenseNumber conn licNumber = do
  let query' = "SELECT id, license_number, full_name FROM get_names_by_fuzzy_license_number_fn(?)"
  PGS.query conn query' [licNumber]
```

And the Sql is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_names_by_license_number_fuzzy_fn(p_license_number VARCHAR)
  RETURNS TABLE
    (id INT
    ,license_number VARCHAR
    ,full_name TEXT
    )
AS $$
  SELECT
    id,
    license_number,
    full_name
  FROM names
  WHERE license_number LIKE '%' || p_license_number || '%'
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

By 'fuzzy search', I mean it searches for any row with a licence number containing as a substring the search parameter `p_license_number`'s value.

**How can I convert this fuzzy search query to Opaleye?**

This would involve getting rid of the Sql file and replacing the `getNamesByLicenseNumber` with a Haskell Opaleye query.
I expect the answer could be something like

```
getNamesByLicenseNumber :: String -> Query NamesColumnRead
getNamesByLicenseNumber licNumber = proc () -> do
  names <- namesQuery -< ()
  restrict -< pgString licNumber .== licenseNumber (names :: NamesColumnRead)
  returnA -< names
```

except with fuzzy instead of strict matching.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly your question is because what you have looks pretty much fine.  There are two things I would improve.  Firstly, pass the string as an argument to a `QueryArr` rather than as a function argument.  Secondly use `like` rather than `.==`.

```
getNamesByLicenseNumber :: QueryArr (Column PGText) NamesColumnRead
getNamesByLicenseNumber = proc licNumber -> do
  names <- namesQuery -< ()
  restrict -< licNumber `like` licenseNumber (names :: NamesColumnRead)
  returnA -< names
```

Does this do what you want?